# UITableViewController does not load data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm new to iOS developing, I have a `UITableViewController` and I want to load `NSMutableArray` data in the table, but it does load data and shows an empty table. It's the code:

```
#import "PhotosTableViewController.h"


@implementation PhotosTableViewController
NSMutableArray *photos;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Photo *pic = [[Photo alloc] init];
    [pic setName:@"over look"];
    [pic setFilename:@"overlook.png"];
    [pic setNotes:@"this is notw!"];
    [photos addObject:pic];

    pic = [[Photo alloc] init];
    [pic setName:@"olives"];
    [pic setFilename:@"olives.png"];
    [pic setNotes:@"this is notw!"];
    [photos addObject:pic];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [photos count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Photo *current=[photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=[current name];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

}

@end
```

Comment: In viewDidLoad try to assign table.dataSource and table.delegate with self.

Comment: how do you create that viewController? Show some code. Because this piece of code works.

Comment: I dragged it from 'Controls'.

Comment: it's whole project files, SDK 4.2 http://mediafire.com/?4yyk241wjl6tp20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[self.view reloadData];` at the end of your `viewDidLoad` implementation.

If that does not help already, I suspect that your viewController is actually not of type `PhotoTableViewController`. Make sure that is correctly setup. If done via InterfaceBuilder, check the type of the viewController and make sure it says `PhotoTableViewController`.

[image]

Comment: I think there is bigger problem, it does not run `PhotoTableViewController.m`, It does not show 'foo' in debugger when I put `NSLog(@"foo")` in `didViewLoad`

Comment: Is the viewController instantiated as a PhotoTableViewController? If instantiated via XIB-file, check the interface-builder and see if that viewController is setup to be of type PhotoTableViewController. I suspect it says UITableViewController and not PhotoTableViewController.

Comment: I'm using storyboard, let me look for it :/

Comment: You saved my second half of day!

Comment: Hehe, my pleasure - have a cup of tea and enjoy the weather for a change ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Le Sigh* you'd be surprised how many UITableView questions are solved with 'Make your class the delegate and datasource.'. In IB, drag the outlets to files owner.  In code, set tableView.delegate = self; and tableView.datasource = self;

Comment: Though that's should be the default for a UITableViewController already.

Comment: It's SDK 4.2.1, can you edit my code? I can't do what you said :(

Comment: Maysam, I don't have the rep to edit your post.  Are you using interface builder, or code?  And Matthias, I can't see the .h, so I can't tell if it's a UIViewControllet subclass or a UITableViewController subclass.  Either way, set it to be safe.

Comment: In SDK 4.2 there is no interface builder separately. it's Table View Controller

Comment: editing questions to answer would be a bad idea anyway. Just add `self.tableView.dataSource = self; self.tableView.delegate = self;` at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method.